# NullPointerException - Trouble with an array of strings

Tags: java

I am having a problem with a getter like :

```
    String[] T2;
    T2=Ti.getT();
```

Where getT() is :

```
    public class MyClass {

        public final String[] T=new String[3];

        MyClass(){

           this.T[0]="...";
           this.T[1]="...";
           this.T[2]="...";

        }

        public String[] getT() {
            return T;
        }


    }
```

I am getting the message java.lang.NullPointerException in the  T2=Ti.getT(); line.

Can anyone give me a clue? Am I using the array correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: What is Ti? Have you initialised it? My guess is you haven't and it is null.

Comment: How are you creating Ti?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The author is asking why the error is occurring, not what is it.

Comment: I am declaring Ti as a MyClass. That is Myclass Ti in another class. I am using composition.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have posted; `Ti` is `null`. Make sure you declare and initialize `Ti` before you try and access it. You need something like

```
MyClass Ti = new MyClass();
```

and you might consider

```
String[] T2 = null;
if (Ti != null) {
    T2 = Ti.getT();
}
```